# py2exe executable generates log file error

Tags: python, mechanize, py2exe, importerror

Py2exe builds the executable without exceptions. When I run the executable, a log file is generated with the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "ecm2es_gui.py", line 10, in <module>
       File "weblogin.pyo", line 4, in <module>
       File "mechanize\__init__.pyo", line 122, in <module>
       File "mechanize\_mechanize.pyo", line 14, in <module>
       File "mechanize\_html.pyo", line 19, in <module>
       File "mechanize\_form.pyo", line 64, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named inspect
```

When I run the program from Python Shell, Eclipse, or Geany I get no errors and it runs OK.

I thought my problem was with the installation of Mechanize or the eggs but now I don't think this is the problem.

Any ideas?  TIA - Brad

UPDATE...  this is my setup.py file:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    import sys; sys.argv.append('py2exe')

    includes = []
    excludes = ['_ssl', 'pdb', 'unittest', 'inspect',
                'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'locale',
                'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar', '_gtkagg', 
                '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
                'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs']
    packages = []
    dll_excludes = []

    setup(
        options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1,
                              "optimize": 2,
                              "bundle_files": 3,
                              "includes": includes,
                              "excludes": excludes,
                              "packages": packages,
                              "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                              "dist_dir": "dist",
                              "xref": False,
                              "skip_archive": False,
                              "ascii": False,
                              "custom_boot_script": '',
                             }
                  },
    #    zipfile = None,
        name='EnerSave Uploader',
        version='0.5',
        description='Upload ECM-1240 Data to EnerSave',
        author='Brad Norman',
        windows=[{"script":"ecm2es_gui.py", 
                  "icon_resources": [(1, "favicon.ico")]}
                ]
        )
```

Comment: What does your py2exe setup script look like?  What are you using for bundle_files and what do you have set for includes?

Comment: Is `inspect` supposed to be in your excludes list?  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: After adding inspect, calendar, etc... to setup.py includes, I realized that I should change my code:

        import mechanize
            to:
        from mechanize import *

The executable generated from py2exe is WORKing!

A noob mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
ImportError: No module named inspect
```

And in your setup script you have **inspect** in the list of excludes.  Remove it from the excludes, and py2exe will package it with your executable so **mechanize** can use it.